# Rails HABTM quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm developing a order system.

```
Models:
   Orders
   Products
   OrderProducts
```

Every product have their own quantity field that tells the user how many there are.

I want to be able to order more than one of the same product and mutiple products. ie. HABTM.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

class OrdersProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :order
    validates_presence_of :q
end
```

I followed this article in setting it up -> [thoughbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159808010/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-conveniences)

But the problem is that I can't access the "q" field when doing this in the console.

```
>> product = Product.create
>> order = Order.create
>> orders_products = OrdersProducts.create :product => product, :order => order, :q => 10

>> order.products.collect{|each| each.q}
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `q' for #<...
```

The article I'm referring to is pretty old however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace your HABTM relationship with a has_many :through relationship. When you add additional attributes to your join model, in this case you want to add the quantity you should use has_many :through instead of has_and_belongs_to_many.

Edit: You could read more about the difference between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many in the railsguide about associations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: The ability to access additional attributes in a HABTM join table was removed in Rails 3.1 in favor of `has_many :through` as described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html